# Remove buttons if a user is logged in on WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, membership

I have these two buttons in the header:

```
<a href="/" class="button primary-button">Members</a>
<a href="#/register/" class="button secondary-button">Register Now!</a>
```

If the user is not logged in or registered, these two buttons should be shown. If logged in, these two should **not** be shown. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: ah okay ill keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) for if user is logged in wp or not

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
// your code for logged in user 
} else {
// your code for logged out user 
}
```

Add Members and Register button  for logged out user you need to used below code

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
  <a href="/" class="button primary-button">Members</a>
  <a href="#/register/" class="button secondary-button">Register Now!</a>
}
```

Comment: I did edit some stuff nevertheless thanks to your code it works @AnkurBhadania

Comment: @JohnBolhano Please accept answer. so it help to other

Comment: how will I do that?

Comment: @JohnBolhano Please check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work OR  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways one can do this. The first one I'll mention will be leveraging a WP function, and the second one using only CSS.

Lastly, I'll end the answer with a way to display a button only to logged in users.

---

**Option 1**

WordPress has a function to determine whether a current visitor is a logged in user: [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) and resembles the following

```
function is_user_logged_in() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
 
    return $user->exists();
}
```

On can find the function in `wp-includes/pluggable.php`.

For your particular case, the following might do the work

```
<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
      <a href="/" class="button primary-button">Members</a>
      <a href="#/register/" class="button secondary-button">Register Now!</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

**Option 2**

Adding something like the following in the `Customize>Additional CSS` might also do the work (it worked for me)

```
.logged-in .button-class { 
    visibility: hidden !important;
    display: none !important;
}
```

or

```
.button-class {display: block;}
.logged-in .button-class {display: none;}
```

---

**Additional**

Alternatively, if one wants to display the buttons only when a user is logged in, using CSS, do as follows

```
.button-class {
    visibility: hidden !important;
    display: none !important;
}
.logged-in .button-class { 
    visibility: visible !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```